# MQL for Persons with Wikipedia Articles

Tags: wikipedia, freebase, mql

I am trying to return a list of people in wikipedia that have dates of birth listed. The code below works for English Wikipedia, but will not return persons in non-English wikis. How can I return a list of people who are in any wikipedia?

```json
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/people/person",
  "date_of_birth": [{
    "optional": "required",
    "value": null
  }],
  "/wikipedia/topic/en_id": [{
    "optional": "required",
    "value": null
  }]    }]
```

Comment: This is not a question. Please clearly state what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally clicked submit before typing question. Updated.

Comment: Regarding getting non-English wikis, my guess would be to change the /wikipedia/ to something like /*wikipedia/. Is the wiki portion of the code above actually what reaches out to wikipedia.org? If not, could you update to show the code getting info from Wikipedia.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freebase has links to non-English Wikipedias, but **only** if the topic also appears in English Wikipedia, so the data you want probably isn't available to query, but if it were, you could use something like this:

```json
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/people/person",
  "date_of_birth": [{
    "optional": "required",
    "value": null
  }],
  "key": [{
    "namespace": {
      "key": {
        "namespace": {
          "id": "/wikipedia"
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Wikidata. new project by wikipedia themselves to link all their data.
http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page

You can also query Wikidata/Wikipedia using Mediawiki API.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php